# Generic Constraint Contravariant Incompatibility in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, generics, union, contravariance, type-parameter

I'm trying to model tagged unions as data.

First I create a `Tagged` utility type, to represent anything intersected with the tag field:

```
type Tagged<T, With extends PropertyKey> = T & { _tag: With };
```

Then I create a representation of a given type.

```
class TypeRep<T = any> {
  T!: T;
  constructor(readonly x: (value: T) => void) {}
}
```

Our representation of fields extends the `TypeRep` like so:

```
class FieldRep<
  Key extends PropertyKey = PropertyKey,
  Value extends TypeRep = TypeRep,
> extends TypeRep<Record<Key, Value["T"]>> {}
```

Records:

```
class RecordRep<FieldEncoders extends FieldRep[]>
  extends TypeRep<UnionToIntersection<FieldEncoders[number]["T"]>>
{}
```

And finally, our tagged union type representation:

```
class TaggedUnionRep<
  Tag extends PropertyKey = PropertyKey,
  FieldReps extends FieldRep[] = FieldRep[],
> extends TypeRep<Tagged<RecordRep<FieldReps>["T"], Tag>> {}
```

This is all well and good it seems... except that we cannot assign a narrow `TaggedUnionRep` instance to the widened type :/

```
declare const a: TaggedUnionRep<"A", []>;
const x: TaggedUnionRep<PropertyKey, FieldRep[]> = a;
```

Surely enough, we get the following contravariance error beneath `x`:

```
Type 'TaggedUnionRep<"A", []>' is not assignable to type 'TaggedUnionRep<PropertyKey, FieldRep<PropertyKey, TypeRep<any>>[]>'.
  Types of property 'x' are incompatible.
    Type '(value: { _tag: "A"; }) => void' is not assignable to type '(value: Tagged<Record<PropertyKey, any>, PropertyKey>) => void'.
      Types of parameters 'value' and 'value' are incompatible.
        Type 'Tagged<Record<PropertyKey, any>, PropertyKey>' is not assignable to type '{ _tag: "A"; }'.
          Types of property '_tag' are incompatible.
            Type 'PropertyKey' is not assignable to type '"A"'.
              Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"A"'.(2322)
```

I'd be greatly appreciative of any tips on best approach to constraining `FieldReps` (ideally not through widening `Tag` to `any`).

[Here is a reproduction of the example above](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKghgcwRAJgHhgGigdQJbAAWUEAHsBAHYoDOUACgE4D2kjoA0hCAHxQC8sKADIoAbygB9YIgBcuAsQC+AbgBQa0JCgBVSnmaUYzAJKUKjGhADGwA5Qx9BAChglyVWlDiUQUAPxQzqTyMACUAnw+fvKUEABuEIwRZBTUdMHyeJQAZklQAEoR-FG+AYVQsQlJ6mrWADZwNHQw4BAFEGAYAt6+fGJqULAAhKHqQ9aGNMCMAK62zIzOjBBwKIb1fiFB8XD1sxChxXzxzHgoEWJKatd1jc1QAGJ4EPUoHV2DUFx+qZ50TFYSU43B6gLYIJAmC+ADU9gd3GkvK1IB8eij2p1oXw-ulYG0PmgOpNGOgftg4fsIABtABEMFpAF0eP1bg0mnRiYt3p00M9XigAKKUSYoJJ0XFeflvD7U5lfSUtAm8vT2YxmCxWWz2PkvN7C0Xi6mUWYAWwARklGXSGcyeGorhp2Q94EhUKrDISvq7Ef8GCwISAfmCA8Cg9xoUNpTywBKPHjo7LGT1E505djfXiMYTXch0FzSYTU7GeDamdhXSzxLcxeyVlBJpRpt5Qog8x7KITaQBBWnYOU8dSN5vbXPu-Se3ngsPkp56mMDnpwFRAA).

Thank you!

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/WJ4vkN) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: @jcalz I just updated this question with a TS playground example :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that their properties `x` don't match.

In your example, `a.x` is a function that takes an object like `{ _tag: string }`, but `x.x` is a function that takes an object like `{ _tag: PropertyKey }`. As in:

```
// these are legal
x.x({ _tag: 'a' })
a.x({ _tag: 'a' })
x.x({ _tag: 5 })
// this is not
a.x({ _tag: 5 })
```

If you were to assign `a` to `x`, the type of `x` would allow you to pass a number or symbol for `_tag`, which may not be well-behaved at runtime.

It appears there is no type-safe way to allow `x` to be any `TaggedUnionRep` without changing the definitions of your types. `UnionToIntersection<PropertyKey>` (i.e. `never`) errors for a similar reason, and `unknown` isn't legal there.

If you really know what you're doing and can be completely sure this is safe, you can set `strictFunctionTypes` to `false` in your tsconfig.json to disable this diagnostic.

Comment: I'm aware of the "why." My question is, how would you approach typing the constraint, such that it's as narrow as possible, without producing the contravariance-related type error.

Comment: @HarrySolovay It appears there is no type-safe way to do it without changing the definitions of your types. `UnionToIntersection<PropertyKey>` (i.e. `never`) errors for a similar reason, and `unknown` isn't legal there.

Comment: @Brbk24 gotcha, thank you! If you add that to your response, I'll give it the green check :)